# Bash cronjob issue for downloading files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron, sshpass

I know how to download all the samples from a SFTP server all at once and using the script mentioned below.

```
#download.sh
sshpass -p password sftp username@X.X.X.X:/Files/2017-05-05-00.zip  ~/local_machine/2017-05-05/
sshpass -p password sftp username@X.X.X.X:/Files/2017-05-05-01.zip  ~/local_machine/2017-05-05/
sshpass -p password sftp username@X.X.X.X:/Files/2017-05-05-02.zip  ~/local_machine/2017-05-05/
.................................................................
sshpass -p password sftp username@X.X.X.X:/Files/2017-05-05-23.zip  ~/local_machine/2017-05-05
```

Instead of running the script ( `download.sh` )  to download all the files at once , How can i download the files on hourly interval. For example , On the above script

The first line in `download.sh` ( download of 2017-05-05-00.zip) need to happen at `7AM` and this is only for the file look up 2017-05-05-00.zip and rest of the lines should not be looked up at.

Second line in download.sh ( download of 2017-05-05-01.zip) need to happen at `8AM` and So on till 23rd file.

When one is getting executed , None of the other files shouldn't be  looked up.

Not sure how to do this using bash cron job  , Any suggestions on how to do this please  ?

Comment: Do you want to download **everyday** files with `2017-05-05` in its filename?

Comment: Look into using at to run your commands at different times/days

Comment: @Cyrus No , For each day the date will be changing. The SFTP server start posting first file at 7AM of a day ( Example: For  2017-05-05 , The first file comes at 7AM as  2017-05-05-00.zip) and it will continue to next day. Even on the next day (  2017-05-06 ) , Last file name will be  2017-05-05-23.zip ( 6AM) and the next day file posting starts (  2017-05-06-00.zip) at 7AM. I know , This is a complex polling strategy that i need to come up with :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this cronjob with GNU date:

```
0 * * * * sshpass -p password sftp username@X.X.X.X:/Files/$(date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H" -d "-7 hours").zip $HOME/local_machine/$(date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d" -d "-7 hours")/"
```

Usually it is necessary to escape `%` with a `\` in a cronjob.

Comment: For the record, the equivalent command would BSD date would be `date '+\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H' -v-7H`